# Amitsur cohomology and limits

Tags: algebraic-groups, galois-cohomology

Let $R \longrightarrow S$ be a faithfully flat ring extension and $\{ G_\alpha\}$ an inverse system of affine group schemes. I would like to know if there is some hope for a bijection like

$$
H^1(S/R, \underleftarrow{\lim} G_\alpha )  =  \underleftarrow{\lim} H^1(S/R, G_\alpha) \ .
$$

Here $H^1$ denotes the Amitsur cohomology.

For instance, this is obviously true when you take a product of affine group schemes:

$$
H^1(S/R, F \times G )  =   H^1(S/R, F) \times H^1(S/R, G) \ .
$$

I think the obvious map $H^1(S/R, \underleftarrow{\lim} G_\alpha )  \longrightarrow  \underleftarrow{\lim} H^1(S/R, G_\alpha)$ is always injective but doesn't look surjective to me, in general.

Is that true? Are there sufficient conditions to make it surjective? For instance, I would have no problem if the $G_\alpha$'s need to be algebraic.

Actually, the case $\mathbf{k} \longrightarrow \overline{\mathbf{k}}$, where $\mathbf{k}$ is a field (of zero characteristic, if this helps) and $\overline{\mathbf{k}}$ its algebraic closure, so that $\overline{\mathbf{k}} / \mathbf{k}$ is a finite Galois extension would be enough for me.

Hence, in this case, I'm asking if there is a bijection between Galois cohomologies:

$$
H^1(\Gamma, \underleftarrow{\lim} G_\alpha(\overline{\mathbf{k}}) )  =  \underleftarrow{\lim} H^1(\Gamma, G_\alpha (\overline{\mathbf{k}}) ) \ .
$$

Here, $\Gamma $ is the Galois group of the extension $\overline{\mathbf{k}} / \mathbf{k}$.

Any hints or references will be much appreciated.

Comment: There's usually a $lim^1$ (or worse) to worry about. See the first section of Milne Compositio Math. 140 (2004), 1149--1175; arXiv:math/0209076

Comment: @anon Thank you! I'll watch your reference: indeed Milne sounds like the right person to talk about this.